# How can I get the filenames from a url in Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: xml, filenames, pentaho

I'm trying to get the filenames that exists on a url. I'm using "Add filenames to result". I put on File/Folder the url: http://aaa.ddd.com/bbb/ccc/ and on the wildcard .*xml$. On this folder exists a file 20130109-002124.xml but when I Get files from the result the filename param has the value "ccc". Every day the file has a different name so I'm trying to read the .xml file name.
How can I read these name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In PDI, whenever you specify a wildcard or regex, you have to remember it's a **JAVA** regex.

This means to specify anything ending in xml, you'd have to use an expression like `.*\.xml`

This is a common source of confusion with PDI.

I don't know if you can just enumerate files on a website though. Never tried that.